# In a UML Class Diagram, how do I show that a class creates an object of another class but doesn't store the object reference?

Tags: java, uml, instantiation, class-diagram

I've got a class which creates an instance of another class. "ServerThread" configures a socket for an incoming connection, and "ServerLogic" waits for any incoming messages.

ServerThread creates an instance of ServerLogic, and invokes the "run" method in ServerLogic. ServerThread does not store a reference to the ServerLogic object, and because these will be running on the same thread, ServerThread will be on hold until ServerLogic stops listening/the socket is closed.

Here is an image of the two classes I'm talking about:

[image]

How would I represent this kind of relationship in a UML class diagram?

Thanks.

Comment: You shared way too much unrelated information. In a UML diagram, a class can describe what variables and methods it has. The method shows the return value's type. Have a dedicated method, or even better a factory class whose single responsibility is to return an instance of ServerLogic. This way you can show this information. What happens with an object or whatever value that is returned by a method (i.e. a reference is stored or not) is not the concern of the UML diagram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand that your `ServerThread` and `ServerLogic` are structurally independent:  no reference between each other is maintained. So there is no association between them.  You could however draw a dependency (dashed line with arrow) from `ServerThread` to `ServerLogic` with the stereotype `«Instantiate»`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Represent it as a 1 to 1 relationship where ServerLogic is a dependent class of ServerThread.

Here is general info on UML if you need that: http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/pvg/misc/uml/